# Assigning the host name to a hadoop job using weka in AWS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hdfs, weka, emr

I have been using the wekaDistributedHadoop1.0.4 and wekaDistributedBase1.0.2 packages on my local machine to run some of the basic jobs. There is a field "HDFS host" which must be filled in order to run the jobs.  I have been using "localhost" since I have been testing on my local machine and this works fine.  I blindly tried using "localhost" when running on AWS EMR but the job failed.  What I would like to know is what host name should I be entering into the field so that weka will call on the correct master?  Is it the public DNS name which is provided when starting the cluster or is there a method in the API which gets that address for me?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to manually do it.

   Create a cluster and keep it alive, you can find info in amazon ec2 instances manage console, in security group elastic mapreduce master/slave. Find it out, login master node and edit conf file and fill with right name.
2. If you need automatically do it.

   Write a shell executed in bootstrap. You can refer to https://serverfault.com/questions/279297/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-ec2-public-dns-inside-a-running-instance

Comment: I did that. Now I have something like my_id@45.68.4.0 as my master node. But I need to pass a security key, no? Where do I install that distributed WEKA, on a local computer?